# How to fix positions of some of the nodes in Networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have recently started to work on graphs with Networkx.
I'm trying to generate a graph with a starting layer and an end layer plus some nodes inbetween.

For example here, I created 2 layers and I'm using the multipartite_layout() to set their positions: [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAqBR.png)

But if with this solution I can't add nodes inbetween those 2 layers without putting them also in layer. I just want to have those initial nodes at a fixed position and then be able to add new nodes that will position themselves between the layers as they are either connected to the first or the second layer (or to a node that is connected to one of the layer).

I didn't found a solution yet because I can't only chose the position of some of the nodes, I have to do it for all of them even tho I need to fix some of the nodes and let the rest chose a position automatically. I tried to look for some different layouts but I did not found a specific one that does the job.

Any ideas on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a neural network styled diagram, try something like this:

```
G = nx.complete_multipartite_graph(5, 3, 4)
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G)

DG = G.to_directed()

edges_to_remove = []
for edge in DG.edges(data=True):
    from_node_subset = DG.nodes(data=True)[edge[0]]['subset']
    to_node_subset = DG.nodes(data=True)[edge[1]]['subset']
    if (to_node_subset - from_node_subset) != 1:
        edges_to_remove.append(edge)
        
DG.remove_edges_from(edges_to_remove)

nx.draw(DG, pos, with_labels=True)
```

which plots

[image: neural_network_plot]

If you truly want to manually position nodes, you can do an automatic bipartite plot and then add individual nodes and edges manually, making sure to give them a position:

```
G = nx.complete_multipartite_graph(3, 2)
pos = nx.multipartite_layout(G)

DG = G.to_directed()

edges_to_remove = []
for edge in DG.edges(data=True):
    from_node_subset = DG.nodes(data=True)[edge[0]]['subset']
    to_node_subset = DG.nodes(data=True)[edge[1]]['subset']
    if (to_node_subset - from_node_subset) != 1:
        edges_to_remove.append(edge)
        
DG.remove_edges_from(edges_to_remove)

DG.add_node(5)
DG.add_node(6)
DG.add_edge(5, 4)
pos[5] = (0, 0)
pos[6] = (0.25, 0.25)

nx.draw(DG, pos, with_labels=True)
```

gives

[image: manually_placed_node_network]

[Note that in the above `DG.add_node(5)` is redundant because `DG.add_edge(5, 4)` will automatically add node 5 to the digraph if it's not already there. I added it just for completeness -- so you know you can use it to add disconnected nodes as with `DG.add_node(6)`.]